# Extreme graphical glitches on Ubuntu 23.10 with Wayland

Tags: nvidia, wayland

Few months after updating to Ubuntu 23.10 I have started getting severe display glitches on Wayland, this alo happens when on X11 but it is much less severe  then it is on Wayland. I have an ASUS TUF Gaming A15 (2021) with an AMD Ryzen 7 4800H CPU, RTX 3050 graphics and 32GB RAM.[image] [image]

Comment: AMD Ryzen is a CPU. The RTX 3050 is a Nvidia card.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 7840U w/ Radeon™ 780M Graphics processor. Let me know if you find a fix to this.

Comment: I have similar issues with my AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 5650U; no Nvidia card installed in my system.

Comment: Yep, Ryzen 7 5825U, Kubuntu 23.10 + wayland is extremly unstable. With Kubuntu 23.04 were smooth (also with wayland).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed glitches in Ubuntu 23.10 on Wayland with the same configuration as [@Acad](https://askubuntu.com/users/1026329/acad) (AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 7840U w/ Radeon 780M Graphics) by adding `amdgpu.dcdebugmask=0x10` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in `/etc/default/grub`. It now reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.dcdebugmask=0x10"
```

Then I regenerated grub config:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After a restart, glitches were gone.

For Intel the solution is to add `i915.enable_psr=0`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"
```

Adding this parameter [disables Panel Self Refresh (PSR)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/include/amd_shared.h#L255C10-L255C10) and causes power consumption to be higher.

[Original solution for Intel + PSR explanation](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2021/09/01/linux-thinkpad-screen-flicker/).

[Original solution for AMD + Fedora by @stephanklein](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/regular-screen-glitch-on-thinkpad-t14s-gen3-amd/79963/13).